# nested for loop bubble-sort logic (python)

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, for-loop, logic

(first time poster, already scared to post lol, apologies in advance, not too sure how to word my question properly but i'll give it a go!)

I don't fully understand the logic itself behind the for loops:

```
# example code

array = [1,6,2,8,3,7,4,9,5]

n = len(array)

for i in range(n-1):
    for j in range(n-i-1):
        if array[j] > array[j+1]:
                array[j], array[j+1] = array[j+1], array[j]
                print(array) # print array is only here so i could watch it sort in terminal.
```

I apologise about how messy my code is and how stupid this question must sound..

I fully understand the if statement since it's just moving along an index, comparing and sorting so to speak;

but I'm not 100% on the logic behind:

```
for i in range(n-1):
    for j in range(len(n-i-1):
```

why do we do n-1 for the first loop and why do we do n-i-1 for the second loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n-i-1` in your inner loop is correct. It is there because after each step, your (n-i-1)th element is in place, and there is no need to re-sort next elements.

Basically, every iteration of the outer loop finds the maximum element in the still not sorted part of the array, and puts it in last place (of these unsorted part). And after each iteration, you get i+1 correctly sorted element at the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

#### You certainly do it with `range(n-1)` for both loops

However, imagine if the first item was 999999 and actually belongs in the last position (after sorting). It therefore has to step along the array all the way from first to last position.

During *just* the first step of the *outer* loop, on every step of the *inner* loop, the 999999 will be pushed forward by one position.

By the *end* of the first step of the outer loop, it will already be in the correct position at the *end*.

Now think what would happen during the first step of the outer loop, if the 999999 had started half-way along the list? Ignore the first few steps, before inner-loop comparisons reached 999999: the 999999 is not yet moving. Once the comparisons reach the 999999, it will advance on every comparison until it gets to the end of the list: it's correct position.

#### Therefore after one step of the outer loop, the 999999 will definitely be correctly positioned

What remains is only the remaining items, followed by the 999999 which is definitely in the correct place already. If it is compared on future outer loops, it will not move. So there is no need to even compare it. We can omit the final comparison of the inner loop, when doing the second step (and beyond) of the outer loop.

#### Induction

The *second* step of the outer loop really only needs to sort all-but-the-last items.

And then the *third* step of the outer loop only needs to sort the "all-but-last-two" items.

Etc.